# How to use Javascript on dynamic created object

Tags: javascript, jdbc

Right now, I want to create a function where if a user hovers over a title link with a specific id (on dynamic created links), it will display a popup box. Right now, it seems to be working on the first link, but it doesn't do it for the other links. I think it's because it has to do with a dynamic created object but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Below is my code in jDBC

**Test.java**

```
out.println("<div id=\"container\">
+ <a href=\"getName?ID=" + result.getInt(1) + "\" onmouseover=\"" 
+ DisplayPopup + "\">" 
+ result.getString(2) + "</a>" //dynamically retrieved name

out.println("<div id=\"descriptionbox\">"
                    + "Name: " + result.getString(1) + "<br/>"
                    + "Birthday: " + result.getString(2) + "<br/>"
                    );
```

**DisplayPopup.js**

```
function popup(path) {
    var ajaxRequest; 

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var e = document.getElementById('container');
        e.onmouseover = function() {
          document.getElementById('descriptionbox').style.display = 'block';
        }
        e.onmouseout = function() {
          document.getElementById('descriptionbox').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", path, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `DisplayPopup`?

Comment: its in the HTML code with the div id "descriptionbox"

Comment: No I mean `+ DisplayPopup + "\">"`...

Comment: [Event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) is the best solution.

Comment: It calls the new servelet in which DisplayPopup.js is located

Answer (score 0):

div id should be created dynamically...see for first link it is container...for next link it shouldnt be same...and like the popup div id also needs to be created dynamically..